# SSRS 2016 Mobile Reports Error with missing dataset

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2016

Does anyone know if it's possible to switch the data set which is used by a Mobile Report? As far as I can see, the only way of doing this would be to add the new dataset and then re-map everything, including filtering to the new one.

It seems a very inefficient way of doing things. In addition, if the original dataset is deleted, there is no way of getting back into the Mobile report!

Any advice appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the Report Portal you can manage the settings of the Mobile Report just like you would with paginated reports. You can set the dataset that it's pointing to there without editing the report. As you might suspect, the field names should be the same or it won't know which ones to use.

[image]

Comment: negotiating with the IT department around permissions - currently I only see two tabs in there - the missing one being the "Shared Datasets" tab! - that does look to be the solution though.. Many thanks!

Comment: Hi Steven. I have checked with our Sys Admin for the instance and we can't see that tab even under his credentials. do you know if it appears in a native mode install, and how to activate / grant permissions to it?

Comment: Yeah, this screenshot is for Native Mode. For Integrated mode, you would find this setting in the report settings in SharePoint. Same concept though.

Comment: We are installed in native mode. Just can't see that tab at all.

Comment: If you're using the Power BI Report Server like me, it has a rapid release cycle so there might be an update available. If you're on the SSRS server, I don't know if this feature is available.